# Testing inconvenience: Android Studio JUnit vs Gradle based: testOptions ignored by Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The following was done with Android Studio 3.4, Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.2 and Gradle 4.10.3.

In the `build.gradle` file, I have configured some unit test options like this:

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
      systemProperty "debug","true"
    }
  }
}
```

I do have a test function that tries to read this property:

```
package com.demo;
public class SysPropTestDemo {
    @Test
    public static void dumpSysProps() {
        System.out.println("sysprop(debug)=" + System.getProperty("debug"));
    }
}
```

When run via command line `gradlew test --test com.demo.SysPropTestDemo` I will get the property `debug` set correctly to `true`. If I run the same test via Android Studio **without setting any options**, the value shown will be `null`.

In order to get the same result from Android Studio, I explicitly have to enter some values in the "Run/Debug Configurations" panel, i.e something like `-Ddebug=true` in the VM options.

Now this is a trivial example, but what I really want to do, is to add some path to the `java.library.path` property in order to be able to load a JNI library compiled within the project. (I do need to write some tests that make use a modified SQLite lib, so not using JNI is not an option here)

It does work when setting additional options, but I think this is very inconvenient, since I can't enter a variable based value in the configuration options (or at least, I don't know how to). To sum it up: when setting or changing values, I do have to go through a bunch of config screens where I would really prefer to have one place in a config file.

Shouldn't Android Studio somehow make use of the values specified in the `build.gradle` file? If not, the docs don't make it clear that the `testOptions.unitTests.all` settings can only be used via `gradlew` invocation.

Answer (score -1):

```
Skybow,

I feel you have two questions
1. How to load jni lib for androidTest(not for 'test[non instrumented unit tests])
   - copy your jni library in corresponding folder [JNI libraries: [app/src/androidTestFLAVORNAMEDebug/jniLibs]
   - load your jni library
     static {

                try {
                    System.loadLibrary("xyzjni");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.error("Exception on loading the jni library : " + e.getMessage());
                }

        }

2. How to make android studio use your config variables defined for unitTests.
   - It would have great if some text file is there which has all configs.
   - Or it is part of build.gradle
   - I don't have any detail on this.
```

Comment: How to load the JNI lib is not really the subject of my question (it does work, if I specify the path in the config panels -- sorry), and from looking at what "java.library.path" if I don't specify anything different, it does not look as if putting the library at some other place will help. Also note, that I am doing local unit tests and not tests on the device.